# how to avoid repetition in tiles definition in a Spring MVC project?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles

I'm starting with Spring MVC using JSP and Apache Tiles. I've learned that I can define views in a tile definition file like:

```
<definition name="index" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/bodies/index.jsp" />
</definition>
```

However going forward like this, I'll need to repeat this simple pattern for every body template, replacing the two appearances of "index". Isn't there a way to avoid this repetition?

Comment: If i understood you correct, you need to add this piece of content to each body content. Why don't you add this repeating content into your base definition (say like header.jsp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiles supports wildcards too. From the documentation here:

http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/wildcard.html

```
<definition name="bank/*" template="/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/{1}.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

The `{1}` now refers to whatever the `*` matched in the view that was called. However, you may find it simpler to just keep the repetition.